# Raspberry Pi cannot find module "ezsheets"

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I have a Python script that uses `telethon.sync` and `ezsheets`, and it works well using Python 3 on my PC. When I try to run it on my Raspberry Pi, it says that it cannot find either module, even though I have installed them both using `pip install`. It is a Raspberry Pi 3. What am I doing wrong?

I have already installed the modules using `sudo pip3 install ezsheets` and `sudo pip3 install telethon`.

Comment: Run `pip list`. Does it have ezsheets and telethon in the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Raspberry Pi, try using:

Python 3:

```
sudo pip3 install ezsheets
sudo pip3 install telethon
```

Python 2:

```
sudo pip install ezsheets
sudo pip install telethon
```

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk I'm not sure what you mean by this comment?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP understands that, but if you insist I will add that.

Comment: I've installed the modules using your commands already

Comment: I'm not sure why it isn't working then. Have you tried updating pip?

Comment: Perhaps you are using python 2, not 3?

Comment: I am sorry, your first answer was correct, I had installed the modules for python 2 by accident! Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @blackbrandt Unfortunately, this is incorrect. On Raspberry Pi's official site, they say to use sudo. There is nothing wrong with using the `--user` flag rather than `sudo`, but it is simpler to install the packages directly with the python installation rather than the user's folder. See here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/software/python.md

Comment: @DapperDuck I've deleted that comment, I did not know that it was different for RPis.